# How to print only the plot on python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am executing the following piece of code to display a plot but the plot gives this description <matplotlib.legend.Legend at ...> . I want only the plot to be displayed. Can anyone please help me how to remove the description and display only the plot.

```
plt.figure(figsize = (15,5))

ax = sns.lineplot(data=df1, x="x", y="y", hue="...",palette=['C6'])
ax =sns.lineplot(data=df2, x="x", y="y", hue="...",palette=['k'])

ax.set_ylabel("Power (W)")

plt.xticks(rotation=90)

legend_labels, _= ax.get_legend_handles_labels()

ax.legend(legend_labels, ['Day1','Day2'], 
          bbox_to_anchor=(1,1))
```

[image]

Comment: Remove both the vertical and horizontal text(number_line)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capture the return value from the last statement

```
_ = ax.legend(legend_labels, ['Day1','Day2'], bbox_to_anchor=(1,1))
```

It happens because Jupyter notebook always displays output from the last statement